# Не обрезается несколько фото Codeignither

Tags: php, codeigniter

В codeignither есть лаба для работы с фото. Использую для того что бы создавать thumb.

Ниже код.

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2'; // выбираем библиотеку
$config['source_image'] = $uploadfile; 
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE; // ставим флаг создания эскиза
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE; // сохранять пропорции
$config['width']    = 350; // и задаем размеры
$config['height']   = 278; 
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); // загружаем библиотеку 

if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()) {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Создается все нормально. Но проблема в том, что если я загружаю несколько фото, например 4, то делается `thumb` Только первого фото, хотя прогоняю все по списку, вывожу `$config['source_image']` что бы посмотреть получает ли он файлы по списку.

Все получает нормально, но все ровно делает только первого фото.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если одновременно (в одном заросе) используется несколько раз библиотека `image_lib` то нужно после каждого `thumb` вызывать функцию

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Comment: Спасибо! зачет.